# I was trying linkedlist program in python and got the error ""'Node' object has no attribute 'next"". '

Tags: python, python-3.x, linked-list

```
class Node:
    def __init__(self,data = None, Next = None):
        self.data = data
        self.Next = Next

class LinkedList:
    def __init__(self):
        self.head = None
    def insertAtBegining(self,data):
        node = Node(data,self.head)
        self.head = node
    def Print(self):
        if self.head == None:
            print("Empty Linkelist")
        itr = self.head
        lstr = ''
        while itr:
            lstr += str(itr.data) + '-->'
            itr = itr.next
        print (lstr)
        
if __name__ == '__main__':
    obj1 = LinkedList()
    obj1.insertAtBegining(5)
    obj1.insertAtBegining(10)
    obj1.insertAtBegining(15)
    obj1.Print()
```

I am getting error in `Node` class saying it does not have `next` attribute.

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't have `next`, it has `Next`, which are different, you can either change `itr.next` to `itr.Next`, or (better, to be consistent with your naming) change your `Node` definition to this:

```
class Node:
    def __init__(self, data = None, next = None):
        self.data = data
        self.next = next
```